# Change of col argument throwing an error and how to store individual graphical parameters

Tags: r, plot

I'll try to define my companies colors and fonts etc to all the plots we're doing. So first question: How can I store them without overwriting the "normal" par settings? I mean can I store all in a "par-Container" and give them to each plot etc?

Ok here I defined the Colors:

```
GRAPH_BLUE<-rgb(43/255, 71/255,153/255)
GRAPH_ORANGE<-rgb(243/255, 112/255, 33/255)
GRAPH_BACKGROUND<-rgb(180/255, 226/255, 244/255)
```

If I do `plot(something, col=GRAPH_BLUE)` I get the error:

```
Error in axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB", ...) : 
  formal argument "col" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

If I do `par(col=GRAPH_BLUE)` and `plot(something)` it works exactly as I want. Why is that? What would I need to change that it works in the first line of code? As I understand it throws the error since there are multiple settings starting with `col` and with `plot(something, col=GRAPH_BLUE)` I overwrite all of them and that's why the axis isn't visible. But is there a special col setting for just the color line of the chart?

EDIT: Ok here's a reproducible example:

```
getSymbols('SPY', from='1998-01-01', to='2011-07-31', adjust=T)

GRAPH_BLUE<-rgb(43/255, 71/255,153/255)
GRAPH_ORANGE<-rgb(243/255, 112/255, 33/255)
GRAPH_BACKGROUND<-rgb(180/255, 226/255, 244/255)

par(col=GRAPH_BLUE)

plot.xts(SPY) #works great
plot.xts(SPY, col=GRAPH_ORANGE) #not really since all axes are missing
```

And the first question is if I could store all these Settings not directly in `par()` but in another variable which I pass to the plot function?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, with a sample of the exact plot you are trying to produce.

Comment: You can make a list containg the parameters for your company template and then pass it to `par` using `do.call` before each plot: `l <- list(col=GRAPH_BLUE, ...)`, `do.call(par, l)`. Or do it like @agstudy suggested, which is even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't a special col setting for just the color line of the chart. You should use `par` or modify the code source of the  function and add it like the case of `bar.col` or `candle.col`. I don't know why they do it for types bar and candle and not for lines? I guess to not have a lot of parameters...

Note the you can save the old parameters of `par` every time you change it.

```
op <- par(col=GRAPH_BLUE)
... ## some plot job
par(op) ## retsore it
```

It easy also to hack the function and add a new col parameters for lines. Only few lines to change in the function:

```
plot.xts.col <- function (old.parameters,lines.col='green', ...) {
.....
  ## you change this line to add the paremeter explicitly
  plot(xycoords$x, xycoords$y, type = type, axes = FALSE, 
   ann = FALSE,col=lines.col, ...)

 ## and the last line since .xtsEnv is an internal object
 assign(".plot.xts", recordPlot(), xts:::.xtsEnv)

}
```